# HTML/PHP Removing part of a html input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to embed Gists from Github that are submitted by users and I am struggling to strip out the portions that I don't need or won't store in my database.

The input looks like:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/user/513968a108093aaad5d8.js">
</script>
```

And the portion that I need is the user/513968a108093aaad5d8.js part.

The site uses HTML, PHP, and JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: You might include some of the things that you have tried, and how they didn't work for your needs, to give folks some idea of what you've already tried (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$val = '<script src="https://gist.github.com/user/513968a108093aaad5d8.js">';
echo substr($val, 37, -2);
?>
```

Removing the first 37 letters (`<script src="https://gist.github.com/`), and then remove the last 2 (`">`).